# Create a custom Permission level based on multiple criteria

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, check-in, item-level-permissions, custom-permission-level

I want to apply permissions for documents uploaded within the folder in a document library where , the permissions are broken for the doc lib and only a particular group's members is going to upload in the folder.

**Note**

1. Have enabled versions for the document library with only major versions.
2. Require documents to be checked out is set as FALSE [NO].
   i cant give contribute permissions for the documents uploaded here, in this folder and users should not edit as well. There is no metadata[ other fields] associated it with this document library.
3. How to create a custom permission level satisfying the above requirements?

this  is my custom permission level, i tried: but somehow , am not able to check-in the document after i uploaded into the folder:

[image: custom-permission-set]

what kind of permission level I need to create for a user to Edit the documents within a folder and check-in the same and DO NOT DELETE as well.

Comment: can anyone who has coded in itemlevel permissions in SSOM,experienced the same  situation ? if yes, please throw some light on this.